# Retornando um objeto. Algum code smell aqui?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, objetos, return

Pensei no seguinte método público:

```
public RespostaDeArme armar();
```

A classe `RespostaDeArme` seria assim:

```
public class RespostaDeArme {

    private final ResultadoDeArme resultado;
    private final Set<Integer> zonasAbertas;

    public RespostaDeArme(ResultadoDeArme resultado) {
        this(resultado, new HashSet<>());
    }

    public RespostaDeArme(ResultadoDeArme resultado, Set<Integer> zonasAbertas) {
        this.resultado = resultado;
        this.zonasAbertas = new HashSet<>(zonasAbertas);
    }

    public ResultadoDeArme getResultado() {
        return resultado;
    }

    public Set<Integer> getZonasAbertas() {
        return zonasAbertas;
    }
}

public enum ResultadoDeArme {
    SUCESSO(1),
    ARME_RECUSADO_PARTICAO_JA_ARMADA(2),
    ARME_RECUSADO_EXISTEM_ZONAS_ABERTAS(3),
    ERRO(4);

    private final int numero;

    private ResultadoDeArme(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }
}
```

Só faz sentido chamar o método `getZonasAbertas()` quando o resultado é `ARME_RECUSADO_EXISTEM_ZONAS_ABERTAS`.

Pergunta: esse código possui algum *code smell*? O único que pensei foi uma eventual necessidade de refatorar a classe que contém o método `armar()` com [Hide Delegate](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/hide-delegate) para não precisar do intermediário `RespostaDeArme` para obter as zonas abertas (o que não sei se seria o caso aqui).

Alguém vê um jeito melhor de implementar esse comportamento? Se necessário dou mais contexto. Não gosto da ideia de ter dois métodos na mesma classe, um `armar()` e um `getZonasAbertas()`, pois os dois teriam um vínculo temporal desnecessário (o programador precisaria saber que deve chamar primeiro o `armar()`, em seguida o outro).

Exemplo de uso:

```
public void executarArme(int idDaCentral) {
    RespostaDeArme resposta = conexao.armar();
    escritorDaFila.escrever(gerarJsonDeRespostaDeArme(idDaCentral, resposta));
}

private JSONObject gerarJsonDeRespostaDeArme(int idDaCentral, RespostaDeArme resposta) {

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    json.put("tipoDeMensagem", Mensagens.RESPOSTA_DE_ARME.getNumero());
    json.put("idDaCentral", idDaCentral);
    json.put("resultado", resposta.getResultado().getNumero());

    if (resposta.getResultado() == ResultadoDeArme.ARME_RECUSADO_EXISTEM_ZONAS_ABERTAS) {
        json.put("zonasAbertas", new JSONArray(resposta.getZonasAbertas()));
    }

    return json;
}
```

Comment: O que são essas zonas abertas? Como é que esses números são usados por quem for chamar o método `getZonasAbertas()`?

Comment: É coisa de central de alarme. Uma partição tem n zonas representadas por números, que devem estar todas fechadas no momento do arme para que este seja bem-sucedido. Falhando o arme devido a zonas abertas, eu mando essa informação para um processo que grava o resultado do arme no banco junto com quais zonas estavam abertas, envia uma notificação para o usuário, etc. O usuário tem a opção de fechar as zonas (manualmente, essa zona é por exemplo um sensor magnético acoplado a uma janela) antes de tentar um novo arme.

Comment: Você pode dar um exemplo de um código típico no qual o método `armar()` e o `getZonasAbertas()` seriam usados? Tentei criar uma outra resposta que não fosse baseada em exceções, mas cheguei a conclusão que para dar certo, eu precisaria saber melhor em qual contexto isso é usado.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Posso tentar, mas não tenho um código à mão, o que tenho hoje é feito de um jeito um pouco diferente e estou tentando fazê-lo mais "correto". Mas basicamente o que vou fazer com essa lista de zonas abertas é incluí-la em um JSON junto com um valor representando o resultado do arme e mandar esse JSON para uma fila de mensagens, aí o outro processo se vira. Hoje eu converto essa lista de zonas em uma String de números separados por vírgulas e mando no JSON.

Comment: Onde está o método `armar()`?  Em que situação `ResultadoDeArme` é `ARME_RECUSADO_PARTICAO_JA_ARMADA`?

Comment: @ramaral O método `armar()` hoje está em uma classe `ConexaoComCentralDeAlarme` mas não sei se é onde deveria estar (é uma das coisas que estou quebrando a cabeça para melhorar, mas isso foge ao escopo da questão atual). O `ARME_RECUSADO_PARTICAO_JA_ARMADA` se dá por um conflito resultante de um usuário (ou múltiplos) tentarem armar via aplicativo e via teclado que fica acoplado à central de alarme, por exemplo.

Comment: Ah, no seu enum `ResultadoDeArme`, o método `getNumero()` poderia ser implementado assim: `public int getNumero() { return ordinal() + 1; }` e com isso você não precisa do campo `numero` e nem do construtor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agora que você editou a pergunta, isso pode ser resolvido com um simples [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), escondendo o construtor e expondo métodos estáticos de *factory*:

```java
public final class RespostaDeArme {

    private final ResultadoDeArme resultado;
    private final Optional<Set<Integer>> zonasAbertas;

    public static RespostaDeArme sucesso() {
        return new RespostaDeArme(ResultadoDeArme.SUCESSO, Optional.empty());
    }

    public static RespostaDeArme armeFalhou() {
        return new RespostaDeArme(ResultadoDeArme.ERRO, Optional.empty());
    }

    public static RespostaDeArme particaoJaArmada() {
        return new RespostaDeArme(
                ResultadoDeArme.ARME_RECUSADO_PARTICAO_JA_ARMADA,
                Optional.empty());
    }

    public static RespostaDeArme existemZonasAbertas(Set<Integer> zonasAbertas) {
        return new RespostaDeArme(
                ResultadoDeArme.ARME_RECUSADO_EXISTEM_ZONAS_ABERTAS,
                Optional.of(Collections.unmodifiableSet<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(zonasAbertas))));
    }

    private RespostaDeArme(ResultadoDeArme resultado, Optional<Set<Integer>> zonasAbertas) {
        this.resultado = resultado;
        this.zonasAbertas = new HashSet<>(zonasAbertas);
    }

    public ResultadoDeArme getResultado() {
        return resultado;
    }

    public int getNumeroResultado() {
        return resultado.getNumero();
    }

    public Optional<Set<Integer>> getZonasAbertas() {
        return zonasAbertas;
    }
}
```

```java
public enum ResultadoDeArme {
    SUCESSO,
    ARME_RECUSADO_PARTICAO_JA_ARMADA,
    ARME_RECUSADO_EXISTEM_ZONAS_ABERTAS,
    ERRO;

    public int getNumero() {
        return ordinal() + 1;
    }
}
```

```java
public void executarArme(int idDaCentral) {
    RespostaDeArme resposta = conexao.armar();
    escritorDaFila.escrever(gerarJsonDeRespostaDeArme(idDaCentral, resposta));
}

private JSONObject gerarJsonDeRespostaDeArme(int idDaCentral, RespostaDeArme resposta) {

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    json.put("tipoDeMensagem", Mensagens.RESPOSTA_DE_ARME.getNumero());
    json.put("idDaCentral", idDaCentral);
    json.put("resultado", resposta.getNumeroResultado());

    resposta.getZonasAbertas().ifPresent(zonas -> {
        json.put("zonasAbertas", new JSONArray(zonas));
    });

    return json;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depende muito de qual é o contexto no qual o método `armar()` será usado. Entretanto, do jeito que está, acredito que sim, que haja aí um code smell de fato, embora não deva ser um code smell grave. Pelo que entendi, uma `RespostaDeArme` que tenha um `ResultadoDeArme` que não seja `SUCESSO` indica que o método `armar()` falhou. O mecanismo correto para denotar falhas assim é o tratamento de exceções.

Assim sendo, o seu código pode ficar assim:

```
public class ArmeException extends Exception {}

public class ParticaoJaArmadaException extends ArmeException {}

public class ExistemZonasAbertasException extends ArmeException {

    private final Set<Integer> zonasAbertas;

    public RespostaDeArme(Set<Integer> zonasAbertas) {
        this.zonasAbertas = new HashSet<>(zonasAbertas);
    }

    public Set<Integer> getZonasAbertas() {
        return zonasAbertas;
    }
}

public class ArmeFalhouException extends ArmeException {}
```

E o seu método `armar()` fica assim:

```
public void armar() throws
        ParticaoJaArmadaException,
        ExistemZonasAbertasException,
        ArmeFalhouException;
```

Comment: O @bigown vai brigar com você, ele prefere retornar códigos de erro nesses casos. :)

Comment: @Piovezan Então, diga para ele que **pode vir quente que eu estou fervendo.** Na minha opinião, códigos de erro são abominações que ainda persistem vindas da era em que exceções não existiam.

Comment: O problema das exceções é que essas situações de erro não chegam a ser excepcionais, elas são até relativamente comuns. Pense no método `InputStream.read()` do Java, que lê bytes e pode retornar `-1` (um código de erro) se a conexão do outro lado foi fechada de maneira limpa em vez de lançar por exemplo uma `ConnectionClosedException`. Agora uma `IOException` é um verdadeiro _showstopper_, capaz de interromper o fluxo normal do programa. Penso que fazer uma exceção interromper o fluxo por um motivo previsível é fazer controle de fluxo com exceções.

Comment: @Piovezan Para ser sincero, a forma correta de tratar isso seria usar uma construção de linguagem que não existe em Java que seria a que permite que uma chamada a um método possa ter várias possíveis saídas, mais ou menos como um bloco `if` ou o operador `?:` que têm duas possíveis saídas cada. Há formas de se simular isso em Java, mas todas elas passam por alguma gambiarra, sejam elas códigos de erro, exceções interrompendo o fluxo, abuso no uso de `if`s ou `switch`es, abuso no uso de lambdas, criação de várias classes complicadas para resolver algo simples, abuso nos casts, entre outros.

Comment: De qualquer forma, vou pensar em bolar uma outra resposta que não dependa de exceções.

Comment: Por curiosidade, como se chama essa construção de linguagem? E em quais linguagens ela aparece?

Comment: @Piovezan Pesquisando um pouquinho, acho que trata-se do [Exclusive Choice](http://www.workflowpatterns.com/patterns/control/basic/wcp4.php), que é uma generalização de comportamentos tais como o do `if` e do `switch`. Só vi ela sendo aplicada no mundo real em alguns poucos lugares tais como em algumas DSLs de modelagem de processos, fluxogramas e BPMN. Acredito que isso possa ser mais ou menos simulado diretamente com um `switch` em uma linguagem que tenha tipagem fracos, tais como o Javascript.